# How to set dropdown list by another dropdown list

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have two dropdown list (let's say there ids are ddl1 and ddl2). How can I set dropdown list 1 (ddl1) equals dropdown list 2 (ddl2) in jQuery?

Something like: `$('#ddl1').val()=$('#ddl2).val()`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thought I'd point out that you're missing the closing ' on ddl2...

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
$('#ddl1').val($('#ddl2').val());
```